# Adding 3 calculated columns together results in my value being off +1 or -1

Tags: calculated-column

I have a total sale price, minus expenses then the following formula is run in 3 different calculated columns to split the Sale Price-Expenses over 3 accounts. The break down for those is 70% 20% 10%. All that changes in the formula between the 3 columns is the % it gets from the sale price-expenses.

=ROUND(IF([DTF/DWI/Admin/Jud]="DTF",([Sale Price]-[Title Transfer]-Towing-[Other Expenses])*0.7,
IF([DTF/DWI/Admin/Jud]="DWI",([Sale Price]-[Title Transfer]-Towing-[Other Expenses])*0.7,
IF([DTF/DWI/Admin/Jud]="Jud",([Sale Price]-[Title Transfer]-Towing-[Other Expenses])*0.7,
IF([DTF/DWI/Admin/Jud]="Admin","$0.00")))),2)

EX: Sale Price=755, Expenses=130.19
formula takes 755-130.19=624.81*70%=437.367 and so on for the other percentages.

So these 3 columns + expenses should = the sale price but I keep getting + or - one penny most of the time. How do I fix this? Do i round out further I have tried up to 6 places and it is still off.

Comment: please share some examples for the current result and the expected result!

Comment: To add to this more, as you can see in the formula the classifications are based on on the value of another Column. Some calculations only use 2 of the 3 accounts but here are a couple of examples.

Comment: Sale Price=760.00 Expenses=166.75 so here is the calculations being done
760-166.75=593.25 Then 593.25 is split into 3 accounts in a 70%,20%,10 split 
593.25*.7=415.28 and 593.25*.2=118.65 and 593.25*.1=59.33, 
So then i should be able to add the expenses plus all three accounts to = the original sale price
166.75+415.28+118.65+59.33=760.01 I end up with an extra penny. I have tried using ROUNDUP, ROUNDDOWN  and ROUND and it will fix some entries but not others. I 'm not sure what i need to do to make this constant. If I use ROUNDDOWN I will end up  -1 cent.

Comment: There is another version of the formula that is used based off a condition that only enters values into 2 accounts in a 70% 30% split but the results are still the same + or - one cent when the calculations are done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was rounding one column up and one column down and then just used Round for the third column... Might not be the correct way to do this but it worked.